# GAE dev_appserver.py isn't downloading the full file locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm getting strange behavior with the local app engine server.

Basically I download a file using this code:

```
startDownloadTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    logging.info("Download Start Time: "+startDownloadTime.strftime("%H:%M.%S"))
    url = '[URL]'
    logging.info("Starting download")
    r = requests.get(url)
    logging.info("Download complete")

    bucket = '/dbdumps'
    filename = bucket + '/dbdumps_'+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'.zip'
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,'w',content_type='application/zip')
    gcs_file.write(r.content)
    gcs_file.close()
    logging.info("Done downloading zip file. Finish time: "+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M.%S"))
```

It seems straightforward enough and works on the production server. The file I am downloading I know should be ~150mb, but for whatever reason,  `requests.get(url)` is only getting/creating a file that's ~33.5mb in size.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it takes longer than 60 seconds it will fail. urlfetch requests have a maximum response of 60sec and only if you set the timeout to that. By default it's 10 secs (from memory). Given the failed download is the roughly the same length each time my guess is this is your problem

Comment: This is correct -- the failure I was seeing was due to hitting the 32mb limit on urlfetch. Moving to requests and using sockets fixed the problem.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about request size ;-)